# Can't use multiple providers with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am using [Tina CMS](https://tina.io) NextJS starter and using it I get this `_app.js`:

```
import TinaProvider from "../.tina/components/TinaDynamicProvider";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <TinaProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </TinaProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I want to use [Chakra UI](https://chakra-ui.com) with this project but when I add the `<ChakraProvider>` (as specified [here](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started)), I get this error:

[image]

How to fix it? Any push in the right direction is much appreciated!

Comment: What versions of `react`, `react-dom`, `next` and `@chakra-ui/react` are you on?

Comment: Please share the full code with your use of ChakraProvider included.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding .js at the end of the import?

import TinaProvider from ../.tina/components/TinaDynamicProvider.js

Comment: I did. No luck!